# Shared folders not available when connected to Windows Server 2008 R2 via SSL VPN

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, sstp

When a user(from a WAN/Windows 7 Professional desktop) is connected via SSTP/SSL VPN, shared folders are not available. But if the same user logs in via within LAN/office-PC, gets to see all the network shares.

Where should I start looking? Many thanks in advance, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ Thomas many thanks for the reply.

Apparently the culprit was the Zone Alarm firewall on the Windows 7 desktop(from WAN; not same domain, just a standalone PC at home) I was connecting **from**. Even though I had added server's IP(static external IP assigned by ISP) in trusted zone, i think it was still blocking some port(s) or something. I uninstalled it and now I can see shared folders/network shares.

Answer (score 0):

You should see if you can manually map the shares, you should also tell us what VPN protocol you're using.

OpenVPN gives the ability to run logon scripts. You can add a 'up' or 'route-up' script to the config which maps the drives in the background. If you're using the OpenVPN GUI it is also possible to create a GUI-specific post-connect script: if your openvpn configuration is named .ovpn then place a script named _up.bat in the same directory. This script will be executed after the openvpn tunnel turns "green".

[Source](http://forums.openvpn.net/topic7746.html)

Comment: @ Jake, Many thanks for the reply. (1) Shared folders are not available via "Map Drive", when i try to map a drive, the server is not there, shouldn't server be there under "Network" ? (2) Regarding protocol: I'm running VPN Server on Server 2008 R2 and connects to it from a Windows 7 Professional desktop via Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol(which uses Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) over port 443 to secure VPN traffic) and GUI I use is built-in Windows 7 -> Network & Sharing Center -> Set up a new connection or network.

Answer (score 0):

Ist the Windows 7 and the Server member of the same domain?

You could use the "net use" command to try several mapping scenarios. Combine Hostname, FQDN and Server IP with explicit user credentials:

- `net use * \\host\share`
- `net use * \\host.domain\share /user:domain\user`
- `net use * \\host-ip\share /user:user@domain`
- ...

I had a similar problem. Maybe my question can help you. But I think I had a rather strange setup: [Can not connect to Windows network share from non domain computer via VPN](https://serverfault.com/questions/347532/can-not-connect-to-windows-network-share-from-non-domain-computer-via-vpn-solve)